# Generate model rows dynamically in odoo

Tags: python, orm, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

Is it possible to make a tree view and use the ORM to fill it?

i know that extending the init function and using  _cr.execute i can fill the view using sql but is it possible using orm functions and python code like search?

this is an example of how to do it with sql:

```
def init(self, cr):
        tools.sql.drop_view_if_exists(cr, 'my_report_model')
        cr.execute("""
            CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_report_model AS (
                SELECT cbl.analytic_account_id AS id,
                    aaap.name AS parent_name,
                    aaa.name AS child_name,
                    cbl.date_from,
                    cbl.date_to,
                    cbl.planned_amount
                FROM crossovered_budget_lines cbl
                INNER JOIN account_analytic_account aaa ON cbl.analytic_account_id = aaa.id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN account_analytic_account aaap ON aaa.parent_id = aaap.id
            )
        """)
```

But i want to do it with python not with sql.

thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your efforts in your question and include current output, expected output.

Comment: I updated the question with an example of using sql, i cant find info on how to do this on the internet and the odoo docs are really basic

Comment: You know that the view is not really a table in database!  What do you mean by filling the view using ORM? Create will try to insert the data using an insert query.

Comment: What i mean with view is odoo Tree View on the interface.I am talking about using an existing model (ex. invoices) and make a tree view on odoo that lists the existing invoices with some changes. i dont need to create new items just show existing ones